# Is there an easy way of embedding a terminal in a GUI application, that uses avalonia?

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

I’m trying to make an application with Avalonia, that would have an embedded terminal. Is there a relatively easy way of doing that?

I tried to make a way of executing commands and return the output, but I was wondering if it’s possible to create ab actual terminal.

Comment: If you can create a rich text editor, then you could use that for the output, and use an input field to send commands to it.